# What counts as "getting away" for the cast master achievement in Animal Crossing New Horizons?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I'm going for the cast master achievement in New Horizons. I know i broke my streak at 58, and that i wont be able to see what my current streak is, but i am wondering what counts as "getting away".

I assume reeling in too soon or late would, since the fish can't be caught after that, but what about casting, and reeling in without the fish knowing. For some reason i find aiming in this version really hard, despite the fact i never used the 3D function in new leaf. Between that and my joycon drift, i doubt i'll ever be able to get it if that breaks the streak too.

Answer (score 10):

I can confirm from my own experience getting the first achievement, the following actions **do not** break your streak:

- Attempting to cast your line, but not being able to land in any water
- Casting your line in water without any fish nearby, and cancelling the cast
- Casting your line in water near a fish, and cancelling before it notices

However, as soon as a fish has spotted your dobber, cancelling it **will** break your streak. This is noticed easily by the fish disappearing.

Basically; if there is no fish, or the fish stays after cancelling, it was a 'safe' cast.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add for anyone checking this in the future, if you reel in before a fish has hit on your line, EVEN IF IT HAS NOTICED IT, it DOES NOT break your streak. I was at 54, cast poorly at a fish, and reeled in to try to reset. Before I hit A to reel in, the fish turned toward the bait and started approaching it, so when I reeled in, it disappeared. I found a different fish and caught it, and in a whim, checked my progress in the Nook phone, and sure enough, it jumped up to 55. I don't know if only losing fish that are actively on the line counts, but if they haven't even nibbled, you're in the clear.